# Get all the names of the applications in a site

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to write a powershell script which gets the names of each application in a website in IIS in order to change the app pool associated with it. I am able to get the website, but I don't see a clear way to fetch each of the names?

Eg. I want to loop through them all: `Api`, `Services`, etc.. and then use

```
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\RootSite\$loopedValue" -Name 'applicationPool' -Value $NewPool
```

I'm trying this:

```
Get-WebApplication -Site 'ABC'

Name             Application pool   Protocols    Physical Path                                                                                                        
----             ----------------   ---------    -------------                                                                                                        
Api              ABC                http         C:\Api
Services         ABC                http         C:\Services
Director         ABC                http         C:\Director
ReportingServer  ABC                http         C:\ReportingServer
```

But there is no way to get the `Name` from the members of `Get-WebApplication`.

```
Get-WebApplication | Get-Member


   TypeName: Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#site#application

Name                     MemberType            Definition                                                                                                             
----                     ----------            ----------                                                                                                             
ClearLocalData           Method                void ClearLocalData()                                                                                                  
Copy                     Method                void Copy(Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement target, bool recurse)                                
Delete                   Method                void Delete()                                                                                                          
Equals                   Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool IEquatable[ConfigurationElement].Equals(Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.Conf...
GetAttribute             Method                Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute GetAttribute(string attributeName)                           
GetAttributeValue        Method                System.Object GetAttributeValue(string attributeName)                                                                  
GetChildElement          Method                Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement GetChildElement(string elementName), Microsoft.IIs.PowerShel...
GetCollection            Method                Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementCollection GetCollection(string collectionName), Microsoft.II...
GetHashCode              Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                                                      
GetMetadata              Method                System.Object GetMetadata(string metadataType)                                                                         
GetParentElement         Method                Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement GetParentElement()                                             
GetType                  Method                type GetType()                                                                                                         
LoadProperties           Method                void LoadProperties(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,System.Object] propCollection)                        
SetAttributeValue        Method                void SetAttributeValue(string attributeName, System.Object value)                                                      
SetMetadata              Method                void SetMetadata(string metadataType, System.Object value)                                                             
ToPSObject               Method                psobject ToPSObject(Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement parent)                                    
ToString                 Method                string ToString()                                                                                                      
Update                   Method                void Update(Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement source), bool Update(psobject data)                
UpdateCollection         Method                bool UpdateCollection(psobject[] arr)                                                                                  
applicationPool          NoteProperty          string applicationPool=ABC                                                                                           
Collection               NoteProperty          psobject[] Collection=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]                                                          
ConfigurationPathType    NoteProperty          ConfigurationPathNodeType ConfigurationPathType=Location                                                               
enabledProtocols         NoteProperty          string enabledProtocols=http                                                                                           
ItemXPath                NoteProperty          string ItemXPath=/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='ABC' and @id='1']/application[@path='/API']            
Location                 NoteProperty          string Location=                                                                                                       
path                     NoteProperty          string path=/ApiDoc                                                                                                    
preloadEnabled           NoteProperty          bool preloadEnabled=False                                                                                              
PSPath                   NoteProperty          string PSPath=MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST                                                                                  
serviceAutoStartEnabled  NoteProperty          bool serviceAutoStartEnabled=False                                                                                     
serviceAutoStartProvider NoteProperty          string serviceAutoStartProvider=                                                                                       
virtualDirectoryDefaults NoteProperty          Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#application#virtualDirectoryDefaults virtualDirectoryDefault...
Item                     ParameterizedProperty System.Object Item(string attributeName) {get;set;}                                                                    
Attributes               Property              Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttributeCollection Attributes {get;}                                  
ChildElements            Property              Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationChildElementCollection ChildElements {get;}                            
ElementTagName           Property              string ElementTagName {get;}                                                                                           
Methods                  Property              Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationMethodCollection Methods {get;}                                        
Schema                   Property              Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema Schema {get;}                                            
PhysicalPath             ScriptProperty        System.Object PhysicalPath {get=$pquery = $this.ItemXPath + "/virtualDirectory[@path='/']/@physicalPath"...
```

I don't really want to parse a `string` value from the `path` or `PhysicalPath` to do this. Is there another way?

Comment: According to IIS configuration system design, applications do not have a property "name" is anyway. So it is the bad design of their legacy WebAdministration cmdlets that leaves such ambiguous mess around. You should switch to "path", as that's the right way to identity an application https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/#attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will provide the application names for all sites:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'IIS:\Sites' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.NodeType -eq 'application'}).Name
```

The following will return the application names for Default Web Site:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' | Where-Object {$_.NodeType -eq 'application'}).Name
```

Comment: The recursive example doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way I came up with was to join the two results from `Get-WebSite` and `Get-WebApplication`

```
(get-website | select-object @{n='Site'; e={$_.Name}},@{n='Location'; e={$_.PhysicalPath}}) + (get-webapplication | select-object @{n='Site'; e= {$_.GetParentElement().Attributes['name'].value + $_.path }},@{n='Location'; e= {$_.PhysicalPath}})
```

Output:

```
Site                          WebType        Location
----                          -------        --------
MEDIA                         WebSite        c:\mir\data
DATA                          WebSite        d:\data
Tu***.M*.A***o.Sa****x.N***e  WebSite        C:\WebSite\Tu***.M*.A***o.Sa****x.N***e
Tu***.***********on.*****ime  WebSite        C:\WebSite\Tu***.***********on.*****ime
Tu***.**.*****.***********ion WebSite        C:\WebSite\Tu***.**.*****.***********ion
Tu***.********.**.****App     WebSite        C:\WEB\Tu***.********.**.****App
Tu***.********.**.****App/api WebApplication C:\Web\Tu***.********.**.****vate
```